# MYSQL select query based on another tables entries

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I have stumped on this as I am a total beginner in MySql.

Here is a the basic of how the two tables are formed

> Table 1
> id,product_id, product_name
>
> Table 2
> id,product_id,active

Now i know how to do a select statement to query the results from one table but when I have to involve two, I am lost.  Not sure if I have to use inner join, left join etc.

So how can I return the results of the product_id from table 1 only if in table 2 is active?

Comment: Also upvote your accepted answers. Its a polite way of saying thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple to join two tables:

```
select t1.* 
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.product_id = t2.product_id
where t2.active = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use JOIN (as Fosco pointed out), but you can do the same thing in the WHERE clause. I've noticed that it's a bit more intuitive method than JOIN especially for someone who's learning SQL. This query joins the two tables according to product_id and returns those products that are active. I'm assuming "active" is boolean type.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND t2.active = TRUE
```

W3Schools has a good basic level tutorial of different kinds of JOINs. See [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp), [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), [RIGHT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp), [FULL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp).